# Non polymorphic containers during runtime

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to store objects in one of several container types, the type of the container is known during run-time. 
The interface of the containers is the **same**, but the containers are **not** polymorphic.

What I am trying to do is avoid the extra jump a vtable forces during runtime - by having a variable that should be of the concrete container type.

Consider that I have the containers:

```
class Vector1<T>
{
     T get();
}
class Vector2<T>
{
     T get();
}
```

And I want to have a container that is either Vector1 or Vector2 depending on some run-time parameter.

So my class should be:

```
Class VectorWrapper
{
      Vector1<SomeType> v1; 
      Vector2<Sometype> v2;

      inline Sometype get()
      {
          **how do I choose between v1 and v2, without the extra jump?**
      }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like premature optimization. Have you measured?

Comment: Yes of course. This optimization is because the performance of this feature is found on a critical path where every jump that we make counts, hence code that can be inlined improves the performance.    We saw actual performance gaps when trying a prototype that uses for example only Vector1 versus the option that uses a polymorphic version of Vector1, Vector2

Comment: Well, then you need to pass the vector to code specialized for that type, i.e. template code.

Comment: @Alf I'm trying with templates, how can I do that, I need to save a pointer to the actual container of the correct type Vector1/Vector2, now what type can I give it?

Comment: If you have to decide anything in runtime, you have to spend time for that. I believe that a jump over vtable is faster than any other solution. If/else and then a jump looks not faster at all. Maybe the compiler optimizes to a jump table, which is at least the same overhead as a vtable :-) In general: Use a profiler to find the real problems instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Klaus To be fair, the OP says (only in the comments, though) that they *did* use a profiler and find the polymorphism to detract performance.

Comment: @Angew: I can't believe that any runtime check and path selection can be handcrafted better optimized than the compiler it already does.

Comment: @Klaus You can hand-optimise it to move it somewhere else. Also, try looking up Alexandrescu's talk about hand-implementing virtual calls to beat the compiler's performance. If you're in tight enough quarters, an **expertly** hand-crafted solution can beat the compiler's generic one.

Comment: A vtable involves two memory accesses (vtable lookup, function pointer in vtable lookup) followed by an indirect call (follow function pointer).  Would one memory access followed by an indirect call be acceptable?  Second, what control (if any) do you have over the code that *calls* `get()`?  What does it look like, roughly?  These correspond to two solutions (manual vtables and hoisting a branch out of a loop).

Comment: @Yakk I have no control over the code that calls the get(), it does not have to be a loop code, it can be called from multiple threads. One jump is better than 2, that is as far as I recall what Alexandrescu's talk is about, but performance wise it is still worse than no jumps. The solution I'm looking for is roughly somehow to store the type of the unknown template, in compile time and than access it in runtime - this way there is no jump. (It might also be impossible at the end..)

Answer (score 3):

To avoid having to decide at runtime, you have to make the decision at compile time. That means using templates. And if you're so time-constrained that there really must be no non-essential jumps on the critical path, you have to keep pushing the tempaltedness higher and higher in your program until you reach a point where the extra jump *can* be made. Yes, this can theoretically mean having >= 90% of your code in templates, but if you *really* need to avoid the jumps, that's the price.

In other words, if `VectorWrapper` must not decide with an `if`, it must be a template as well. And so must be the code using it, etc., until you eventually reach a point where the `if` is not so expensive.

If you find that this templated part is too big, but can at least be isolated somehow, you could even do something like build several shared libraries (with different template arguments in each) and at runtime, load the one version containing the correct combination of template arguments.

Comment: That's what I've seen so far myself.. Was hoping there can be some templates magic done that can help with that. We also ruled out loading libraries at runtime (for various reason I won't go into here).

However, you mention that I should go upper the hierarchy up to a point I can pay the extra jump, but on the critical path there is no such point. On init I am willing to pay practically any price, on the critical path no price.

Comment: @MaxShifrin Then template the whole program, and do the decision at init time. Or is that not an option for some reason?

Comment: Well templatting everything is out of the question as the entire project is several millions of lines of code :-)

Comment: @MaxShifrin If you really have a several-million-LOC critical path, it will of course take a *lot* of work to optimise anything on it. Only you can tell what work is worth it.

Comment: Yes, that is my point, we cannot afford to rewrite such a path all with templates usage just because of this optimization, since the effort is to big. Hence came my question, which tries to find a solution, as I mentioned - it is possible that the solution I'm looking for in this case is not possible. (without rewriting everything with templates which is out of question)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is vague.  So all I can provide are vague solutions.

The first technique worth considering is a manual vtable.  This removes a memory indirection compared to an automatic vtable.  Basically you store a function pointer to the right implementation of the method, and you follow that function pointer directly.

A second approach is hoisting the branch out of a loop.  Your code, to matter, must be run repeatedly.  If the decision asto which branch to take is made before the repeats, you can move the branch out there.

Imagine you had

```
void foo() {
  bool which_branch = decide();
  VectorWrapper wrap( decide );
  wrap.populate();
  for (auto x : some_loop_domain) {
    x.set( wrap.get() );
  }
}
```

notice that the decision is made outside of the loop, but the price may be paid within the loop.

If we can move the branch *outside* the loop, the cost is paid once instead of once per element in `some_loop_domain`.

One way to make this work is to provide the compiler with an easier to optimize constant.  So we avoid storing the state for which vector is in use within the wrapper, and instead pass it in.  The value we pass down is arranged to be "obviously constant" in the context where it is used, or even a compile time constant.

To use a compile time constant, the code using it must be templetized.  However, this templetization need only be at the "above the loop" point, as a branch there is usually cheap enough to not care.

To rely on the optimizer being reasonable, you similarly populate an obvious constant there and pass it down as a value.  This can be less reliable in my experience.

```
void foo() {
  bool which_branch = decide();

  auto body = [&](auto which_branch) {
    VectorWrapper wrap( which_branch );
    wrap.populate();
    for (auto x : some_loop_domain) {
      x.set( wrap.get() );
    }
  };
  if (which_branch) {
    body( std::true_type{} );
  } else {
    body( std::false_type{} );
  }
}
```

now within `body`, `which_branch` is a compile-time constant.  All by itself this may result in the branch being  hoisted, but it may require:

```
  auto body = [&](auto which_branch) {
    static_assert( decltype(which_branch){} || !decltype(which_branch){} );
    VectorWrapper<decltype(which_branch)> wrap;
    wrap.populate();
    for (auto x : some_loop_domain) {
      x.set( wrap.get() );
    }
  };
```

where we make `VectorWrapper` a `template` on a class that when instantiated and read in a `bool` context returns `true` or `false` as a `constexpr`.

The code within `VectorWrapper` remains similar, except it reads the compile time constant instead of a method to decide which branch to take.

This technique can be very intrusive or not at all.  It can take seemingly branch-filled code and hoist the branches out.

You can do a cartesian product of many low-level branches in a similar way, where you can generate 2^10 different low-level routines, pick between them before entering the loop, then running one of the 1024 loops.

Comment: thanks for the elaborate answer, but there are some assumptions which are not true such as: the code does not have to run in a loop, it can be repeated accesses regardless of a loop per say, also as I already mentioned pushing the templates high enough the hierarchy is not really an option. I do find the manual vtable concept rather interesting, but it still has the overhead of 1 jump, as compared to 2 in a normal vtable.

Comment: @max there are very very few programs where a certain bit of code is run many many times (enough that following a pointer on modern hardware is going to matter) that do not contain a loop.  Maybe you have such a case, but your passive voice indicates that you do not seem to know.  Such cases are rare, so I doubt it.  Having actual concrete cases where you have detected a performance problem by profiling would make your problem more realistic, and then you would know there is no loop or not. (And if you knew there was no loop, I would say you should question your certainty!)

Comment: I try to give only the details relevant to the question, without going into where exactly in our product and what exactly our product requires to do with these bits of code, as these do not matter and as I am not allowed to expose these obviously. As I already mentioned we are looking into this because of very thorough profiling and trying to fix bottlenecks, the software is very optimized. Due to the nature of the software it has to deal with a lot of concurrent requests, where each must completely quickly, and usually won't have any loops on the critical path.

Comment: @MaxShifrin One problem is that you don't know the solution; knowing what is needed to determine solution is thus difficult.  Stripping it down is good, but you also need to provide context.  Knowing the answer to your problem, and knowing exactly the details relevant to the question, are often the same thing; and by asking the question, you provide evidence you don't know the answer to the problem, so you don't know *exactly* what details are relevant.  I'd guess, at this point, you might be HFT or somesuch, where latency between decision and execution matters at tiny time scales.

Answer (score 0):

Make the part of your program where those containers are used parameterized on the container type:

```
template<class Container>
void criticalPath()
{
    // Create and use Container objects a lot
}


void enterCriticalPath(bool useVector1) {
    if (useVector1) {
        criticalPath<Vector1<SomeType>>();
    } else {
        criticalPath<Vector2<SomeType>>();
    }
}
```

Comment: but you are forcing to do the "init" on every call of the critical path instead. This is the same as having the if/else inside the critical path. Unless you can think of a way to store the pointer to the template container somehow, I couldn't thin of a good way.

Comment: @MaxShifrin: "*This is the same as having the if/else inside the critical path.*" How is *starting* the critical path itself part of the critical path?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas obviously the init of the critical path is not time constrained, but the suggestion above forced me to have an if else in every place I want to call my functionality along the critical path. enterCriticalPath does not store the instance a concrete class as a variable, it simple calls the relevant function according to the input, no jump is eliminated here.